# Android Studio AI 140

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

[Not useful anymore]

I just updated to the latest version of Android Studio from Canary chanel and I have this error (see below).

I just open the new Android Studio, click on my project and wait to see the error. The popup

> Gradle sync in progress

remains, but it does not do anything. And all the project is 'broken' : it does not find reference to anything.

I'm mac Mac OS X 10.10.2

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalSystemShortcutsManager.getActionId(ExternalSystemShortcutsManager.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalSystemKeymapExtension.getActionPrefix(ExternalSystemKeymapExtension.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalSystemKeymapExtension$ExternalSystemRunConfigurationAction.<init>(ExternalSystemKeymapExtension.java:240)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalSystemKeymapExtension.updateRunConfigurationActions(ExternalSystemKeymapExtension.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalSystemShortcutsManager.scheduleRunConfigurationKeymapUpdate(ExternalSystemShortcutsManager.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ExternalProjectsManager.init(ExternalProjectsManager.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity$1.run(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity.runActivity(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:79)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$2.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:336)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$700(StartupManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$3.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:259)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.access$700(DumbServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl$9.run(DumbServiceImpl.java:424)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Do you have any indication of which line in your code is throwing the NullPointerException?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no clue :  I just opened Android Studio, click on my project and wait to see this error

Comment: Ah; it's actually the program throwing the NullPointerException. Have you tried the trivial steps like re-installing the latest versions of both, Android Studio and JRE?

Comment: I'm switching to an older version of Android Studio. I think there is a bug in the latest one. (I'm in canary chanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution :

**Create a new project** and **copy/paste the sources** from the old project to the new one.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

**Try using the standalone version**, so that you can always go back to a working setup ([download link](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/1-2-preview-1)). Plus, make a backup of your Studio preferences (just i case).

Moreover, try performing `Invalidate caches/Restart` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That's what I did, (go back to a stable version) the invalidate caches/restart AS/restart computer/unplug the coffee etc didn't work :p

Comment: Too bad, sorry then. I am running the 1.2 preview on OSX 10.9 and haven't found any issue so far. Wait for a more stable version ;)